# Predefined webform configuration for specific content type

Tags: 7, webforms

I'm new to Drupal, I need to create a job list page with an application form for each of the job listings presented in it.

I've created a "Job" content type, and installed the webform module

When I create a new Job, I'm able to create a form and present it in the content of the job. 
The problem is that it has to be done for each specific job listing manually

Is there a way to set the configuration of the webform attached to a specific node by its content type? 
A code based solution is preferred - but one that is based on action in admin UI is also blessed

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can able to do it using admin UI.

Follow below instruction.

**Add new field (boolean type) at webform content type.**

Make this field as a checkbox.

**Add "Entityreference" module**

enable it

**Create entityreference view using views UI for webform content type and add above created boolean field in FILTER CRITERIA  select operator > is one of "yes"**

I have attached snapshot for views UI

[image]

**Now edit manage field on job content type**

**Add new field on job content type give the name and select "Entity Reference" in data type.**

**Now select "select list" option for widget click on next button.**

**Next page will be shown Entityreference option at there you need to section "view" for the first drop down "Views: Filter by an entity reference view" and second "View used to select the entities" pick you entity reference view which you have created prviously and save it.**

Snapshot for above description

[image]

Now you will able to select created webform on job node.